# Master Detail Page Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

Aright, let me try to make it a bit simple,

When i Login: i set the my root page as a Normal ContentPage,

```
var firstPage = new BaseNavigationPage(new DashBoardPage());
(DashBoardPage is just a contentPage, with few buttons)
```

On click of the buttons, i navigate my app, using

```
NavigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.CommentPage);
```

Now on DashbOard, there is button, which redirects me to a Page which is a MasterDetailPage, so using some custom thing,
i navigate by setting my MasterPage,

```
NavigationService.SetMainPage(ViewModelLocator.MASTER_PAGE);
```

Following is my MasterDeatilPAge Code;

```
var menuPage = new MenuListPage();
            Master = menuPage;
            Detail = new CustomNavigationPage(new WorkTaskPage());
```

Now , on the Menu Page, i have an List Item as DashBoard, and i have to redirect my App to the first Page, 
So how can i do that, since with MasterDetail Page, i can either Navigate Detail Page or Set the Detail Page,

So how can i redirect it to the Dashboard Page, and i want all navigation to work normally when i am on dashboard page, without changing any navigations.

Hope this is a bit clear?

Comment: You have to provide some code and explain it better, because your above post is really messy.

Comment: Your code/example is pretty sparse but here are some suggestions depending upon how you have things structured.  (1) Bind the Dashboard list item to a command on your view model that when fired tells navigation service to navigate to the dashboard page, (2) if you are using a messaging service send a message to navigate back when the list item is clicked.  You have to, in some way, know the user tapped the list item and then use a command or message to navigate "back" or set new main page.

Comment: You can define a navigation reference on app.cs and you can navigate pages over this for example App.Navigation.Push/PopAsync(new YourPage());